# Refinishing options for metal sink drainplug?

Tags: drain, sink, metal, refinishing

The drain-plug in the sink of my bathroom vanity is made of a plastic base with a metal top (brass by the looks of it) that is chrome plated.
[image: drain plug]
The chrome-plating developed some scratches which turned black over time (oxidation I presume).
My cleaning lady couldn't stand the eye-sore and got too enthusiastic with the polishing. She used Brasso copper-polish on it and managed to cut through the chrome-plating and through the underlying copper-plating as well. (You can see the yellow brass coming through just left and top of the center.)
That was last week. Now the exposed copper-plating is starting to go dark as well.

I can't easily get a replacement. This plug was made by a factory that went bankrupt 10 years ago.
It is a peculiarly shaped part of the whole faucet and drain assembly on the sink. (Faucet has a lever at the base which pushes the drain-plug up from below when the drain is closed. The plug itself is a seperate part, but the plastic base goes 3" into the drain where it sits on top of the lever. The metal top is glued or epoxied to the plastic base. I can't separate top and base without damaging the base.)

To make matters worse the plug is a non-standard size, in between the standard small and large drain-plugs. I can't just put in a standard rubber plug. This also makes replacing the whole drain-faucet assembly a problem due to non-standard sizes.

The wife is really starting to nag me about the eye-sore... Something needs to be done.

So, my best idea so far is to refinish the metal cap. I have never done anything like that so what are my options?

Comment: Your description of how the plug fits into the drain sounds bog-standard to me. Seems that the only issue is the diameter. While this may be difficult to find at a home improvement center, I'd suggest that a plumbing supply place may have an aftermarket replacement. If you can't go in in-person, at least give a few a call with some precise dimensions (and the name of the original manufacturer) to see if they can help you. That would probably be much easier than having the surface re-chromed.

Comment: Remove it sand all that gunk off spray paint  a couple light coats of metallic silver   Then a couple coats of satin clear coat.. it will look good until it doesn’t..  then repeat the steps.

Comment: @FreeMan I have tried a dozen suppliers already. The original brand was not a well-known supplier selling to general plumbing suppliers. They only made stuff for the house-brand of one of the major DIY chains. And every supplier I called is closed due to lock-down. Only do business by mail-order via web-shop for the regular run of the mill stuff. (Half of them I even couldn't get a human on the phone at all. Just the answering machine telling me to go to the web-site.)

Comment: @Kris I was thinking along those lines myself. I've got some metallic silver and clear-coat enamel paint (for RC models) at my disposal.

Comment: Yeesh! Sorry to hear that. What a pain. :/ You might go with @Kris' suggestion (which should be an answer), or opt to replace.

Comment: @FreeMan You never know... Just got of the phone with supplier 15. The lady there started to laugh about halfway into my story. Turned out she had exactly the same vanity at home and the same problem 2 years ago. She also had the solution. When the factory closed the inventory and designs were bought by Grohe, who integrated them in their sub-brand "Ben". They still make them. Slightly different plastic base nowadays, but they fit. The only thing is that Grohe calls them 'waste plug" instead of "drain plug", so you never find them in Google unless you know that. My replacement is on order.

Comment: Excellent news and shows the value of not giving up! Please write that up as an actual _answer_ (down there vvv), then accept it. That will make it much easier for others to find in the future.

Comment: @FreeMan I will write a self answer later when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been trying, in vain, to find a replacement plug for days.
Hence I was looking towards refinishing options.

Due to Corona lockdown all shops here are closed. Plumbing suppliers with a web-shop still do mail-order, but I wasn't having any luck finding a match for the plug.

I resorted to emailing/chatting to customer support on various webshops without much success. And I started calling every plumbing supplies and installation outfit in a 50 mile radius.

Miracles do happen apparently...

Called supplier nr. 15 on the list.
The lady there started to laugh about halfway into my story. Turned out she had exactly the same vanity at home and the same scratching problem 2 years ago.
She also had the solution.
When the original factory closed 10 years ago the inventory and designs were bought by the company Grohe, who integrated them in their own sub-brand called "Ben".
They still make them. Slightly different plastic base nowadays, but it fits.

The reason I couldn't find anything online... Grohe calls these "waste plug" instead of "drain plug", so you never find them in an online search unless you happen to know you need to look for "waste plug".
Additional confusion is caused by the fact that Grohe calls this a 5/4" plug, but that doesn't match any of the actual dimensions of the plug. 5/4" happens to be the size of the pipe-fitting on the siphon that goes under the sink.

So I got my replacement ordered and I can forget about refinishing the original plug.